# Appropriate AWS Service for Media(video) Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application which streams video like(NetFlix, Youtube).

I am trying to host it in the AWS platform. I have found two different options with this:

- first one is store video files in s3.
- the second one is store video files in AWS MediaStore.

In my existing platform, I have a problem with downloading video through IDM by end users.

So, I have to prevent downloading the video from IDM.

How can I do this in the AWS platform? Which AWS service will suit my case of preventing downloading?

Answer (score 1):

Please take note of data-out charge when you use AWS as the primary mean to serve your video streams. **Personally I found It prohibitively expensive to use AWS's service to serve your video**

Netflix for example use S3 as a part of main storage for their video streams.

To the question of which service you can use to hide direct link / download link from AWS. Currently there is no service provided natively by AWS for that purpose

Comment: so @qkhanpro, Is there any mechanism in s3 such as bucket policies and access control mechanisms where i can restrict download for all users via IDM?

Comment: To solve your first problem you can write your own web application that stand before your datastore.
That allow user to request video stream chunk by chunk. Some thing like this: 
https :// your-server.com/file/1?continuationKey=xxxXXXxxx  ...
The client side will only get your data by chunk ( may be 20 second video each time ) and that will make it harder for anyone trying to steal your content. This involve some coding though. Maybe you can start another question for that...

Comment: Can you share some reference links for this method. It would be great.

Comment: Look at this site you can imagine It http://movies.hdviet.com/phim-truy-tim-ufo-project-blue-book.html#FmE7tiaqdmBoTLOW.97